# Display video using video tag and servlet

Tags: java, html, jsf, servlets, video

I am displaying a video in my .xhtml page using html 5 video tag and a java bean and a servlet as my video file is located on my server

```
  <video controls="controls" style="margin-top: 60px;width: 70%;height: 80vh">
                    <source src="/SPortal/VideoReader" type="video/mp4" />
                </video>
```

My bean :

```
    @PostConstruct
public void prepeareMethod() {
    //check the type of learning object
    try {
        LearningObject lo = dao.getLearningObjByID(reqId);

        String learnObjType = lo.getLearningObjTyId().getLearningObjectType();
        initialFile = new File(lo.getDirPath() + "\\" + lo.getFileName());
        InputStream targetStream = new FileInputStream(initialFile);

        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(false);

        session.setAttribute("loBytesArray", IOUtils.toByteArray(targetStream));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

my servlet:

```
 @Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    byte[] pdfBytesArray = (byte[]) request.getSession().getAttribute("loBytesArray");
    request.getSession().removeAttribute("loBytesArray");
    response.setContentType("video/mp4");
    response.setContentLength(pdfBytesArray.length);
    response.getOutputStream().write(pdfBytesArray);
}
```

The problem is I get this error at my servlet specially at the writing part over the response output stream :

`Warning:   Setting non-serializable attribute value into ViewMap: (key: lessonLearnBN, value class: com.beans.LessonLearnBN)
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[VideoReader]: Servlet.service() for servlet VideoReader threw exception
java.io.IOException: Connection closed
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
Severe:   Error Rendering View[/Error.xhtml]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response`

Any idea what is the problem??

Comment: I noticed it works on Internet explorer but not on chrome ,opera or firefox

Comment: Are you allowed to use OmniFaces? If so, use http://showcase.omnifaces.org/servlets/FileServlet if you are not, fire the one who descided that ;-)

Comment: Thanks alot for your response , I could you OmniFaces but is there anything i can do to make this code works??

Comment: If you really  want to make this work, start with a [mcve] so others van try to reproduceren if they want to